# Is the sequence bounded?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is the sequence $x_{n}=\sum_{k=2}^{n}log_{k!}\frac{k+1}{2},n\geq 2$ bounded?

My tried to expand that expression and change bases, but I only made everything even more complicated..

Answer (score 3):

Let us reformulate the question into:

Is the series with positive terms:

$$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}a_k \ \text{with} \ a_k:=log_{k!}\left(\frac{k+1}{2}\right)$$

a convergent series (the $x_n$ appear as the partial sums of this series) ?

**First proof** : Using Stirling approximation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation),

$$a_k=\dfrac{\ln(\tfrac{k+1}{2})}{\ln(k!)}\approx\dfrac{\ln(k+1)-\ln(2)}{k \ln(k) - k}\approx\dfrac{1}{k}$$

Being equivalent to the general term of the harmonic series, this series is divergent.

Said otherwise, as its terms $a_k$ are positive, its partial sums tend to $+\infty$, thus are not bounded.

**2nd proof:**

Lemma 1: $\forall  k \geq 2, k \in \mathbb{N}, \ \ \dfrac{k+1}{2} \geq \sqrt{k}.$ (easy)

Consequence : taking the natural logarithm on both sides : $\tfrac{\ln(k+1)-\ln 2}{\ln(k)} \geq \tfrac12.$

Lemma 2: $\forall  k\geq 2, k \in \mathbb{N}, \ \ \ln(k!) \leq k \ln k.$ (even more easy)

Then, using Lemma 2 and the consequence of Lemma 1:

$a_k=\dfrac{\ln(\tfrac{k+1}{2})}{\ln(k!)} \geq \left(\tfrac{\ln(k+1)-\ln 2}{\ln(k)}\right)\frac{1}{k} \geq  \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{k}$

The general term being less than a constant times the general term of the harmonic series, the given series is divergent.

Comment: Yeah, but that s a sum and you have not used any criteria to actually prove that it is divergent. I think your proof is not really clear.

Comment: @Christian I'm sorry but it's a criteria by equivalence is a *classical* criteria for series with positive terms. See for example page 4 of this document: (http://c.caignaert.free.fr/sl-chapitre8-04.pdf): sorry, it's in French but I think it is understandable because the terms are almost the same that in English.

Comment: I have added a second proof using minoration criteria.